# Why is my footer when set at 100% wider than any other element?

Tags: html, css

I want the background colour of my footer to span 100% of the webpage but it ends up wider than my navigation bar and img which are both also set to 100%. Also, I get a gap between the footer and image which I have corrected by using bottom: -76px but was wondering if there's a better solution that'll be more responsive.

```css
main img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
}

footer {
    background-color: #DE002B;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    bottom: -76px;
    width: 100%;
}

footer p {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <img src="Photos/Prague 1.jpg" alt="A picture of Prague.">
    
    
    
      
   

  </main>
  <footer>
    <p id="footer">Company Registration Number: </p>
    <p id="footer">VAT Number:</p>
  </footer>
```

Comment: add `box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 0;` to the footer

Comment: Your footer is 100% + 10px padding on each side. Try:
width: calc(100% - 20px)